# Step math function

Tags: math, rounding

I need function which returns:

- for any number from  range => result

  `[0.001,0.01) => 0.01`

  `[0.01,0.1) => 0.1`

  `[0.1,1) => 1`

  `[1,10) => 10`

  `[10,100) => 100`

  etc.

My first idea was to use `if`, but this the worst way. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: What do you want, simply the upper end of an interval? Mathematically, that's what the sup function does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
10^(floor(log(x) + 1))
```