# C# log base 10 and rounding up to nearest power of 10?

Tags: c#

if i have a number between 100 and 1000 i want to get the value 3 because 10^3 = 1000. Likewise, if i had a number between 10 and 100 i would want to get the value 2, because 10^2 is 100.

Incase you're wondering, its to do with calculating a probability and i always need to divide through by 10^value, to keep the probability between 0 and 1. For example if i calculate 9256, i need to divide through by 10^4, so that i get a probability of 0.92

I'm not sure how to do the rounding up and how to do the base 10, could someone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Step math function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907949/step-math-function)

Comment: Should 10 go to 10 (and thus have a probability of 1.0) or 100 (and have a probability of 0.1)?

Answer (score 10):

```
Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just take the log of the number and then round it up? Log 9256 will give you 3.966, round it up to 4 (add one and integerize it if you want), then divide by 10 to the power of 4... you practically answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using the logarithm will work, but you'll also need to consider the rest of the calculation.  Dividing out the powers of 10 may be simpler for you:

```
double Scale(double x)
{
    if(x <= 0} { return 0; }

    while(x > 1.0)
    {
        x /= 10.0;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Yeah... this solution is probably more efficient.